# What is this red book Gilfoyle holds in season 4, episode 3?

Tags: silicon-valley

In *Silicon Valley* (season 4, episode 3), I'm wondering what's the exact book Gilfoyle holds. I tried reading the title on pause, but the text is unreadable. Thank you!

[image: screencap of scene described above]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book is [Mathematical Fundamentals of Fuzzy Information Processing](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/%E6%A8%A1%E7%B3%8A%E4%BF%A1%E6%81%AF%E5%A4%84%E7%90%86%E7%9A%84%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%A6%E5%9F%BA%E7%A1%80.html?id=5JPQAQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y%22) (模糊信息处理的数学基础) by Ren Ping and Yu Dong.

[image]